# Proving that length of a curve is $\infty$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a differentiable and continious function in $(0,1]$ and $lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\infty$. Prove that the length of the curve on (0,1] is $\infty$. 
Steps I tried: $L=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+f\prime(x)^2}dx\geq\int_0^1\sqrt{f\prime(x)^2}=\int_0^1f\prime(x)=f(1)-lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-\infty$ (and I had to prove $\int\geq\infty$ and not $-\infty$).

Comment: @Babak S. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question is wrong, because in order for $f$ to be continuous at 0, it has to be bounded near 0, but your claim that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\infty$ means that $f$ is unbounded at 0, contradiction. I think you mean that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=\infty$. Then, you get the limit as $\infty$ from your computation.

P.S. From one of your steps, $\sqrt{f'(x)^2} \neq f'(x)$, but it is $|f'(x)|$. So I think you just need to change that equality into inequality

**Edit** in response to edited question:
Then, once we have $\int_0^1 \sqrt{f'(x)^2}=\int_0^1 |f'(x)| \geq |\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\int_t^1 f'(x)|=|f(1)-\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)|=|-\infty|=\infty$

This corrects and finishes the proof.

Comment: The modification given above makes sense, because $f(1)$ is not  necessarily defined (The $f$ is defined on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Actually, if you care alot about rigor, we should note that the inequalities bring to improper integration, thus if you want to be fully rigorous, you gotta write limit sign, then noting that the limit as $x$ goes to 1 brings $f(x)$ to $\infty$

Comment: wrote the question wrong but now I fixed it.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner I just edited my response